# Customize touch bar button when using the browser?

Tags: touch-bar

Can I turn off the touch bar when I use the browser like Chrome or Safari?

Sometimes, I click the Reload button unknowingly when I fill the website form. This is a nightmare for me, especially for filling long questions.

I only found this article from official,
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207055#customize

But it doesn't mention how to customize setting except for default touch bar.

OSX: 10.14

### Update

I want to get rid of the reload button like the following.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your Touch Bar? `Shift + Command + 6`

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu Bar → View → Customize Touch Bar

Drag the reload button on your Touch Bar into the trash can on the far left side of your Touch Bar (or just off the Touch Bar).

[image]

More info from [Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7570714?hl=en).